# Atualizar banco de dados com AJAX Switche button (Materialize)

Tags: php, ajax, materialize

Estou usando o FrameWork Materialize, nele tenho um botão (Switche) que alterna entre *ON* e *OFF*, apenas no html, eu queria inserir isso em um banco de dados Mysql, tudo em tempo real, ao pressionar o botão, ele altere o valor no banco de dados, 0 para *OFF* e 1 para *ON*, ao pressionar o botão, se no banco de dados estiver 0 altere para 1, e visse e versa, se no bando de dados estiver 1, o botão deve permanecer ligado, isto é, simbolizando o *ON*! (O botão no materialize eu um checkbox, checked deveria ser igual a *ON*)

HTML:

```
  <div class="switch">
    <label>
      Off
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span class="lever"></span>
      On
    </label>
  </div>
```

No PHP eu pensei em algo tipo assim:

```
$valor = $_POST['Switche'];

if($valor == 1){
    $valor = 0;
}else{
    $valor = 1;
}
```

Como posso fazer isso e atualizar no bando de dados em tempo real ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode enviar os dados do formulario para o servidor usando a [api fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) (ajax "nativo"). O codigo necessario para isso é esse:

```
 <div class="switch">

    <label>
      Off
      <input type="checkbox" id="escolha">
      <span class="lever"></span>
      On
    </label>
</div>

<script>
    var escolha = document.getElementById('escolha');
    escolha.addEventListener('change', function(){
        atualizarSwitch();  
    });

    function atualizarSwitch(){
        var escolha = document.getElementById('escolha');
        var formulario = new FormData();

        var escolha_estado = 0;

        if(escolha.checked === true){
            escolha_estado = 1; 
        }

        formulario.append('switch', escolha_estado);

        fetch("servidor.php", {
            method: "POST",
            body: formulario
        }).then(function(resposta) {
            return resposta.text();
        }).then(function(resposta) {
            alert(resposta);
        }); 
    }
</script>
```

Basicamnete é adicionado um evento [onchange](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) para a checkbox, e depois capturado o valor de marcado ou desmarcada, criado um objeto [formdata](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/FormData/append), e posteriormente enviado para a url **servidor.php** usando a api fetch.

Já o servidor pode ser feito assim (arquivo **servidor.php**):

```
<?php 
$valor = $_POST['switch'];

if($valor == 1){
    $valor = 0;
}else{
    $valor = 1;
}

echo $valor;

//quando construir a função chame descomente a linha abaixo
//salvarNoBanco($valor);

function salvarNoBanco($valor){
    $conexao = mysqli_connect('host', 'usuario', 'senha', 'nome_banco');
    $status = mysqli_query($conexao, 'UPDATE nome_tabela SET algum_campo = ' . $valor . ' WHERE algum_campo = alguma_valor_condicao');
    return $status;
}
```

Para uma referenicia das funções de `mysqli_*` consulte no [w3c](https://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_mysql_intro.asp).

Comment: E caso eu quisesse com múltiplos checkboxs? Só por curiosidade, eu não sou o autor da  pergunta.